# Filter RSS feed for custom post type to events for next 7 days only

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts, rss, meta-query

I'm trying to create a custom RSS feed that shows posts from the custom post type 'events' for the next 7 days ahead only.

The feed is already sorted by event start date order rather than published date through the plugin, I just can't figure out how (as a beginner in PHP!) how to limit the feed to only the 7 days ahead. This is the query I have so far, which works fine until I try to filter the feed against a date and then it returns no posts :-(

Any pointers much appreciated!

```
date = date("d-m-Y");
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime("+7 day", $date);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'showposts' => 10,
    'meta_key' => 'st_date',
    'meta_type' => 'date',
    'value' => $date,
    'compare' => '<'
    );

query_posts($args);
```

Comment: There aren't uquite enough details here. How exactly you are creating the feed? What plugin is involved in it? How are you trying to filter?

Comment: Hi Rarst,
The feed is created using an RSS template I created from a tutorial. I know the feed template works fine as if I take the query down to just 'showposts' is works. It's just the more complex query I'm struggling with. The plugin is EventOrganiser.

I'm 99% sure it's my query that's wrong more than anything else.... possibly date formats but I'm learning as I go here! :-)